# Magento2 extension: add link to product grid

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm developing extension for `magento 2.1.3 ce`. I want to add a link to each product in the products grid in admin-panel:
[image]
I want to have a link in this column, how to change my extension to have a link instead of plain text?

My Magento extension code (*`app\code\MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml`*):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
       <column name="sku">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Field2</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">75</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

in pseudo code what i want is:

```
<column name="{http://mysite/}"+"sku">
```

Comment: you can add it same as actions column.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Do you have an example? How should be it implemented via DataSource? or DataModify?

Answer (score 1):

If the URL is internal, try this:

Step 1: config the column like this:

```
<column name="custom_field2" class="MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\HTMLLink">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
           <!-- other configurations -->
           <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Step 2: create file `<Magento_ROOT>/app/code/MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/HtmlLink.php`

```
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;

class HTMLLink extends Column{
    protected $escaper;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        Escaper $escaper,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource){
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $html = '<a href="some_internal_url" target="_blank">product</a>';
                $item[$fieldName] = $this->escaper->escapeHtml($html, ['a']);
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }

}
```